# issue while using spring data gemfire repository functionality while querying data from region

Tags: java, caching, repository, spring-data, gemfire

We use a third party library to get data from an external gemfire cache cluster. We also connect to our own gemfire cache cluster. We use client cache to connect to our cluster and the third party library has its own client cache defined in its own application context.

The third party library does not use "spring data gemfire repository" functionality whereas we do. We are facing issues while querying our cache using the "Spring data gemfire repository" functionality depending upon the order in which the application context's gets loaded. If our context gets loaded first then everything works where if the third party gets loaded first then our query call fails though save works fine.

On debugging what I found was in the later case, the default-pool referred to in the query-service points to the third party cluster and hence does not have our regions.

Due to enterprise constraints we do not have control over the order in which the application context gets loaded. Is there any way we can customize the default pool being used so that even if the third party app context gets loaded we are still able to override the default pool to point to our locator pool rather than any other?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the client region(s) associated with the repository to use a separate pool using the pool-name attribute.

Comment: We are using spring data gemfire 1.3.3.RELEASE and spring data commons 1.5.3.RELEASE with gemfire 6.6.3. 

We do have the pool defined against the regions in the client cache, but for some reason when the SimpleGemfireRepository executes the query using the StringBasedGemfireRepositoryQuery which in turn calls the lookupQueryService it returns the queryService with the locator pool associated to the other cache cluster rather than the pool associated with the region.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Could you submit a JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF